# Using vue.js in Shopify liquid templates

Tags: vue.js, shopify, liquid

This should be simple but despite searching I was unable to find any solution to this. How do you use vue template tags within a liquid file? Since both Vue and liquid use the same curly brackets, I'm unable to render any of my view data:

```
<img src="{{ product.featured_image }}" />
```

results in:

```
<img src>
```

There are 36 products in my parent view component.

When I try to use custom delimiters:

```
new Vue({
  delimiters: ['@{{', '}}'],
```

It won't parse with Vue:

GET https://inkkas.com/collections/@ 404 (Not Found)

UPDATE: I'm able to access Vue data with v-bind: but I still need to be able to use delimiters also.

Comment: Use binding instead interpolation `<img :src="product.featured_image" />` - in case the `product.featured_image` is JS stuff.
Also you could set your own vuejs delimiters - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42166251/vue-js-does-not-render-correctly-using-template/42166634#42166634

Comment: for some reason that binding is taking the entire element out of the dom now.

Comment: Does console says anything ?

Comment: Nope, not when I bind. When I try to using custom delimiters it's not parsing with Vue: new Vue({
  delimiters: ['@{{', '}}'], ....

Comment: You need to use `` back ticks not "" or ''

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Apparently with Shopify, you can't put these delimiters in the tag attributes at all so for those use v-bind: (the shorthand won't work). Also you have to use a single curly brace for your custom delimiter or it will still try to parse with liquid, for example:

```
delimiters: ['${', '}']
```

will work with:

```
<span class="title">${ product.title }</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding on a bit from where Kevin Compton left off, this is where you put the "delimiters" parameter:

```
const ConditionalRendering = {
  data() {
    return {
      seen: true,
      someMessage: "My message"
    }
  },

  delimiters: ['${', '}']
  
}


Vue.createApp(ConditionalRendering).mount('#conditional-rendering')
```

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for this answer.